# Mailing the form information using PHPMailer

Tags: php, jquery, http, backend

I have created a form and I want to mail the form data using PHPMailer. What can I do?

My contact.html file:

```
    <script src="../../Scripts/Custom/contact.js"></script>
<div class="contact-container">
    <div class="form-container">
        <p class="contactus-heading">Contact us</p>
        <div class="inner-form-container">
            <div class=" form-row "><input type="text" id="name" class="contact-form-text" placeholder="Your Name here" name="name" /></div>
            <div class="form-row"><input type="email" id="email" class="contact-form-text" placeholder="Email" name="email" /></div>
            <div class=" form-row"><input type="text" id="phone" class="contact-form-text" placeholder="Phone Number" name="phone" /></div>
            <div class="form-row"><textarea class="contact-form-text" id="body" placeholder="your message here" name="message"></textarea></div>
            <div class="form-row buttons">
                <input type="submit" onclick="sendEmail()" name="btn-send" class="send-btn contact-form-btn" value="send" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

My Contact.js file:

```
function sendEmail() {
    var name = $('#name')[0].value;
    var email = $('#email')[0].value;
    var phone = $('#phone')[0].value;
    var body = $('#body')[0].value;
   
    if (isNotEmpty(name, email, phone, body)) {
        debugger;
        $.ajax({
            url: '../../Pages/Shared/mail.php',
            type: 'POST',
            name: name,
            email: email,
            phone: phone,
            body: body,
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response);
            }, error: function (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        });
    }
}
function isNotEmpty(name, email, phone, body) {
    debugger
    if (name != "" && email != "" && phone != "" && body != "") {

        return true;
    } else {
        console.log('some fields are empty');
        return false
    }
}
```

My mail.php file:

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

 if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email'])){
     $name=$_POST['name'];
     $email=$_POST['email'];
     $phone=$_POST['phone'];
     $body=$_POST['body'];

     require_once "../../Libraries/PHPMailer.php"
     require_once "../../Libraries/SMTP.php"
     require_once "../../Libraries/Exception.php"

     $mail = new PHPMailer();
     $mail->isSMTP();                                            // Send using SMTP
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';                    // Set the SMTP server to send through
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = 'mailhere';                     // SMTP username
    $mail->Password   = 'password here';                               // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'TLS';         // Enable TLS encryption; `PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS` encouraged
    $mail->Port       = 587;  
    
    $mail->isHTML(true);  
    $mail->setFrom($email, $name);
    $mail->addAddress('mailhere');     // Add a recipient
    $mail->Subject = 'It is a subject';
    $mail->addReplyTo('mailhere');
    $mail->Body    = $body;

    if($mail->send())
        $response="Email is sent!";
    else
        $response= "Something went wrong :<br><br>".$mail->ErrorInfo;
    exit(json_encode(array("response" =>$response)));

 }
?>
```

When I filled the information in the form, The error I got is:

The request sent to the Web server used an HTTP verb that is not allowed by the module configured to handle the request. \t

A request was sent to the server that contained an invalid HTTP verb.

\t

The request is for static content and contains an HTTP verb other than GET or HEAD.

\t

A request was sent to a virtual directory using the HTTP verb POST and the default document is a static file that does not support HTTP verbs other than GET or HEAD.

Comment: Hi, can you tell us something about your hosting environment (if your script runs on a server) or about your dev environment,  if you work locally

Comment: I am using visual studio for localhost

Comment: First, find out whether it is the first request (the ajax call) that fails. To do that, remove all the stuff from your mail.php file and just `echo` something there. Then check the `console.log` output

Comment: Nothing printed, it is not executing the mail.php even though the path is correct. I also moved the mail.php in the same folder, still it did not executed

Comment: I strongly suggest you start again from scratch, step by step, to get a working ajax call first. Then, see how you transfer data with ajax to the mail.php script. Then, add the PHPMailer code...